# Pytorch _pickle.UnpicklingError when loading .pth model with torch.load(PATH)

Tags: pytorch, model

When running this github repo:https://github.com/yelusaleng/RRU-Net/blob/master/predict.py, I met the problem in  the title.

My running enviroment is :python3.7, torch1.0.0;

I use best_model.pth(provided in the repo:https://github.com/yelusaleng/RRU-Net) as input model.

The specific running error is :

`File "predict.py", line 67, in net.cuda() File "/root/miniconda3/envs/RRU2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 367, in load return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module) File "/root/miniconda3/envs/RRU2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 528, in _load magic_number = pickle_module.load(f) _pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered, but no persistent_load function was specified`

For now,I have two thoughts to fix it:

1. persistent_load function problem? How to specify this func? I read the train.py file in the same repo, it just used torch.save to save the model.

```
torch.save(net.state_dict(),
                   dir_logs + '{}-[val_dice]-{:.4f}-[train_loss]-{:.4f}.pkl'.format(dataset, val_dice, epoch_loss / i))
```

2.model problem? Is it right to just use best_model.pth as input? Or I should train the network first and use my own model?